# Selenium C# finding alert and verifying text

Tags: c#, selenium

I am looking for an example for a verification that a javascript alert has taken place. I have a script that goes to a login page, and attempts to login to the system. I have a test case for a successful login, and I am trying to work on a failed login case. Any suggestions for automation best practices would be appreciated. So to boil my question down it is simply "How to I verify that this alert has happened on my webpage?"

HTML

```
<div class="alert">
The username and/or password entered are invalid.</div>
```

Test

```
    [Test]
    public void failedCustomerLogin()
    {
        //Finding the customer login link and clicking it
        var customerLogin = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Homepage_r2_c14"));
        customerLogin.Click();

        Assert.AreEqual("http://stage.blank.net/login", driver.Url);

        var userName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
        userName.SendKeys("badCustomerName");

        var Pasw = driver.FindElement(By.Id("password"));
        Pasw.SendKeys("BadPassword");

        var submit = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSubmit"));
        submit.Click();

        //TODO: need to find failed method
        string errorText = driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Text;
        Assert.IsTrue(errorText.Contains("The username and/or password entered are invalid."));
    }
```

Wait Selenium

```
        //Waiting for error to display
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

Comment: `string errorText = driver.SwitchTo().Alert()` switches you to JS alert. you seem to be dealing with some additional html being added to the DOM, which happens to have css with name "alert". these two are different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that actually worked for the given alert, as Saifur pointed out the alert isn't really an alert. I was able to dig down to the class level and verify that the text appears on screen with the following code.

```
        var errorMessage = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'alert')]"));
        Assert.IsTrue(driver.PageSource.Contains("The username and/or password entered are invalid."));
```

Comment: That's what I assumed. Sorry could probably have saved you some time. But, was busy at work

Comment: No need for an apology sir! you helped me out quite a lot in this matter.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following and assert if the expected text exists depending on the Testing framework and assertions you use.

```
string text = Driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Text;
```

I use *NUnit* assertion and in my case it looks like the following

```
string text = Driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Text;

Assert.IsTrue(text.Contains("The username and/or password entered are invalid."));
```

**2nd edit: adding explicit wait**

Try adding explicit wait

```
Driver.FindElement(By.TagName("test")).Click();

//Make sure the click above generates the alert
String text = (new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))).Until(d => d.SwitchTo().Alert().Text);
Assert.IsTrue(text.Contains("The username and/or password entered are invalid."));
```

Comment: When I run this in my NUnit console, I get the error NoAlertPresentException : No alert is present. How do I get my system to recognize the alert? Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to click on element first that generates the alert and possibly add some wait time for the alert to generate

Comment: So above I have the code for submit.Click() and I am attempting a wait just after the click. It doesn't seem to be waiting past 10 seconds.

Comment: @DEnumber50 Not sure why it did not work. I added some explicit wait. Do not mix implicit wait with that.

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 10 seconds----> OpenQA.Selenium.NoAlertPresentException : No alert is present (This is the error I get when running the above suggestion)

Comment: @DEnumber50 are you sure that's an alert?

Comment: Well the html is included above as class = "alert", is that not the case?